# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Origin checking failed -during django admin panel login in google cloud server

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, django-csrf

I am encountering the following error on the Google Cloud production server when attempting to log in to the admin panel. However, it is functioning correctly on the local server. I have followed the official Google Cloud documentation and added the following code, but the error persists: Django version:4.0I have include this code in setting.py also

I've made an attempt to address the issue persisting despite my efforts.

Comment: CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL = env("CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL", default=None)if CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL:ALLOWED_HOSTS = [urlparse(CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL).netloc]CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL]SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = TrueSECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")else:ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]